# Stop USB Device from Passing Power to Machine

Tags: usb, usb-device

**Summary:**

The RC Controller that I'm using for a PC game to practice flying quads is, I suspect, passing power through the line and causing my machine to shut down.

**What I'd Like To Do:**

Change the wire configuration so that my PC stops crashing

**Details:**

- RC Controller: FlySky FS-i6
- Game: Liftoff on Steam
- Cable Connection: S-Video to 3.5mm Audio Jack to USB converter

I have the USB dongle open. I think if I can just find a way to stop power from being passed into the machine it'll work, but I'm not sure, that's why I'm here.

I've tried using USB ports on both the motherboard and also USB ports on a dedicated USB card. Both produce similar results. Not long after starting the game and using the controller, the entire PC restarts. In the years I've had this machine, I've never experienced this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you are going down the wrong path, thinking its power coming from the controller, its more likely a SW issue or HW issue with the PC.....can you give more information on why you think its power from the controller?

Comment: The reason I suspect the power from the controller is the issue is because I've had wonky usb results in the past while powering an arduino externally as it was plugged into my machine. It never caused the machine to shut down but there was an effect

Comment: I would expect that if your controller was externally powered, and directly hooked up to the usb, but its cable to dongle to usb. 
before doing any mods to your usb dongle, I would suggest using a USB hub in between to see if you get the same results.  If you do, then I would start looking at the drivers and SW first. or try another PC.

Comment: The controller is externally powered also. It has 4 double A's and won't work unless it's turned on with the batteries in

Comment: externally I mean using a wall adapter or mains power. and also, from the dongle its only getting data from the controller. if you have an O-scope or other means, put it on the data lines going into the dongle, and check voltage and whats being sent.

Comment: I have a multi-meter and a Saleae logic analyzer. Ill give it a go

Comment: it soulds a lot like a driver problem - ask in superuser.

Comment: Are you actually using an RC controller, that is emitting a radio signal, attached to the PC?

Comment: @EdgarBrown no, typically there's a PPM signal out of the back of the RC transmitter that is roughly equivalent to what would have been used to modulate the transmitter in the old analog days.  It's there to be sent to an instructor's transmitter in a "body box" teaching setup, but it can also be read into a PC.  Typically it would be coupled in via a capacitor, the idea that it is injecting power and causing restarts is mistaken.  At most it might be conducting RFI, but even that is doubtful. More likely bad software.  **This is an off topic usage question, not an EE design question**

Comment: USB port should be protected on the computer side against over current, so I would be surprised the reason is that it's drawing too much current. It might be Static ESD causing a reset. How does the computer stops ? blue screen or just power off instantly?

Answer (score 0):

USB port should be protected on the computer side against over current, so I would be surprised the reason is that it's drawing too much current.

It might be Static ESD discharge causing a reset on some chip of the motherboard.

Static would build-up on your body, transmitted to the remote through the metal joysticks and to the ground line of the USB going right onto the motherboard, as it seems there is no shielding connected on your usb dongle.

Try to connect a wire from some metal part of your remote to the PC casing (make sure it makes good contact) and check if it still happening.

Comment: I took the shielding off the dongle so I could get a photo and see if there was any broken solder points lol. I have a ESD bracelet, I'll try hooking it to my controller and see if that works.